# Displaying content when a checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I check a checkbox

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id=“checkbox” name="area" value="storage">     
  Storage
</form>
```

I want  to show and when I uncheck it I want it to be hidden!

I have the following as a start:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(){
if ($('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
    /* NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE */
}
```

})

Comment: `$('#something').show()` and `$('#something').hide()`

Comment: Or simpler than the duplicate: `$("#checkbox).click(function() {
    $("#something").toggle(this.checked) });`

Comment: I tried the above and created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jnoweb/c1khz1cs/ but this what I've tried doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Several errors. No jQuery selected in the jsfiddle. Wrong ID used to assign checkbox event. Storage visible on load

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4o6x5atk/